# Does glove size make any difference?

Tags: boxing, mixed-martial-arts

I am a noob when it comes to mixed martial arts and boxing. I was just curious what difference does the glove size make in MMA as Mcgregor was happy that Mayweather agreed to reduce the glove size to 8 ounces. Is it an advantage for an MMA person to have lighter gloves?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With no context yes, but in this situation (McGregor vs Mayweather) very little, if any.

MMA gloves are 4oz. Many of the strikes that land in MMA would not land if they were wearing larger gloves. This is due to the massive surface area of boxing gloves. Even 8oz gloves (let alone 10oz) will allow a defender to block strikes, or at least cause them to be glancing strikes (less powerful) compared to what they would have been with 4oz gloves.

A boxer gets used to being able to "shell up" and be safe. That's not really a thing in MMA (to the same extent), as you can sneak in shots that wouldn't have been possible with larger gloves.

So we've established that smaller gloves are better for MMA fighters because that's how they're used to fighting. Good. Here's the problem in this specific scenario: **Mayweather is already used to this glove size.**

There won't be any strikes "sneaking through" that he's not used to. he has fought with 8oz gloves before, and has proven to be a master of defense, even with the smaller gloves.

So to answer your question, **going from 10oz to 8oz likely will not make a big difference. If any, the slight edge may go to McGregor.** McGregor prefers the change, as he wants the gloves to be smaller (as small as possible). Mayweather doesn't care, as 8oz is nothing new to him (hand speed increase is negligible as both fighters benefit.) If the gloves got even smaller, to 6oz or 4oz, then that would be a different story. With 8oz though, it's still within the range that neither fighter should gain much more of an advantage.

That being said, as an MMA fighter, if I had to fight a boxer under boxing rules I would absolutely push for 8oz gloves over 10oz gloves. Every tiny little shred of possible advantage is worth pursuing.

Answer (score -3):

In my opinion, Mc Gregor , was already out of advantage, by 50 percent, and May weather in confidence by a 90 percent win...
Any martial artist will be in a disadvantage if he forsake his principal rule of his individual art, (a risk) already in the frame, Mix Martial art champion, uses diffirent skills, from the Boxing rules.... May weather, a tactical Undefeted champion to the title is no idiot, as for the gloves in both arts the fughter will make sure he wears the right size of gloves in the regulations in which the punches are going to be felt within the gloves and the power used to maximise hand/punch knuckles to the opponent.... Nothing to  be of surprise or a question i believe, because the main issue on the fight is to win, cross punches, upper cuts, etc, the opponent has to feel the knock out punch through the gloves, and the knuckles that are being landed upon in the individual skill.
Mc Gregor, took a chance, way below the equel range of their individual art, by giving in to the boxing rules, to a Tactical World Undefeted champion...
If Mc Gregor, would have won that fatefull day, than the history of Martial arts and Boxing, would have taken a shocking, Genius world record..
Lol.. Cheers Guys.

Comment: I would strongly recommend looking up [the tour](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works…